# Tell Blender to ignore tracker for camera solve

Tags: tracking

I want to have blender ignore some markers during camera tracking. I have drone footage of someone running around on a rooftop and shooting at "things" to be added post.  I tracked his gun barrel before doing the camera solve. Naturally if that marker is included in the solve, I get a massive error.  If I delete that marker, I get a good solve. I spent a lot of time putting in that gun barrel track (frame by frame). Can I tell blender to ignore it (or more trackers) during the solve?

Comment: Why not delete that track altogether?

Comment: That is what I did, and then I added an object to save the tracker under.  I had to track the gun barrel by individual frame, and I didn't want to throw away 20 minutes of work. I realize that is small potatoes, but I figured it might save me more time in the future. I am beginning to believe it is not possible - that all trackers linked to the camera are used, and that is the intent of the programmers.

Comment: Well, if you would like to keep the marker, you could clear the tracks, then re-track all of them except the one you wish to exclude. Tracks are calculated individually depending on which ones you select, and the solve will reflect that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to delete the tracker.

Each tracker can be assigned a weight, which determines the tracker's contribution for the final camera or object solve.

Just bring the value to zero.

[image]

More info: https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.70/Motion_Tracker